# 403 Error in Cybersource - what permissions do we need to call the API

Tags: cybersource

We are trying to call the Cybersource API and are getting the following message:
errors:
type: forbidden
message: Request not permitted

(please see image attached).

We are using this API https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#token-management_customer_create-a-customer and the authetication keys for the current test account we have.

The question will be: What permissions should we take into account to be able to call that API?

Thanks for any help!

Chris

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhFuh.png)

Comment: Hi Chris, are you able to solve the issue? I am getting the same error and don't know what is happening wrong. First I thought it was the profile ID header missing in the request. So I generated a new profile ID and sent it with the same, but the response is the same.

Comment: @attacomsian may I ask how did you generate a profile id?

Comment: @Community, the profile ID is provided by Cybersource. You can get in touch with their support team and ask them to provide you with a TMS Profile ID for your account.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a very similar issue to you just the other week - and was able to get some feedback from the CyberSource team.

Basically - **they only have payment services in the sandbox environment** - the rest of the services (like token management) will be available in test environments once contracts are in place.